# Sprunge this! Sprunge that!

Tags: code-golf, internet

Your task is to create a program or function that creates a paste on [sprunge.us](http://sprunge.us). Your program/function must receive the text to *sprunge* from your language's usual input mechanism, such as standard in; or in the case of a function, it can be a string or whatever makes the most sense to you. Your program will POST the text from input to `http://sprunge.us/` as `multipart/form-data` with the form field name of `sprunge`. Finally, your program will output/return the URL sent back in the reply from the POST.

This is a code golf, so shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Here is an example solution using `bash` and `curl` taken directly from the sprunge.us website. Feel free to use it in your own golf:

```
curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

Which returns the URL to the paste, which looks like `http://sprunge.us/aXZI`, where the `aXZI` is the ID of the sprunge.

*This is my first code golfing challenge, please let me know if this is too easy or not creative enough*

Comment: So, you're not allowed to write a function? Nice challenge, by the way.

Comment: Correct, it must be a complete program. Thanks by the way. I have a feeling there might not be much room for improvement from the curl example... I could make this a popularity contest if that's the case.

Comment: sprunge seems to be down (503)?

Comment: Bummer! :( Maybe I should remake this question to use [ptpb.pw](https://ptpb.pw)...

Comment: @devRicher looks like it's back up, sorry about that. I have no control over sprunge.us.

Comment: Why can't we write a function?

Comment: And I doubt anybody will improve on that curl code. (though if I've golfed the code, can I post an answer using the golfed curl code?)

Comment: I'm going to revise the question to allow functions & yes you can base your solution off my example.

Comment: I agree the example I gave was a bit too concise for a code golf challenge. With any luck, somebody will come up with a curious alterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bash, <strike>29</strike> 25 bytes

```
curl -F sprunge{=\<-,.us}
```

Thanks to @Score_Under for providing this awesome solution!

Old solution:

```
curl -Fsprunge=\<- sprunge.us
```

Quotes around 'sprunge=<-' are unnecessary, as long as the `<` is escaped.

EDIT: Interestingly, this alternative way has the exact same length:

```
a=sprunge
curl -F$a=\<- $a.us
```

Comment: Can be shorter with careful use of brace expansion: `curl -F sprunge{=\<-,.us}`

Comment: @Score_Under Thanks! updated

Comment: @Markasoftware The space between `F` and `s` is important.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 30 bytes

```bash
curl -F'sprunge=<-' sprunge.us
```

Just removed the unneeded space in `-F 'sprunge=<-'` and the `http://` from the `sprunge.us` url.  OP gave me explicit permission to golf his reference solution.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML, 88 bytes

```html
<form action="http:sprunge.us" method="POST"><textarea></textarea><button type="submit">
```

To test this easily, prepend `data:text/html,` to the code and paste it into your address bar (works for me on chrome).

Full (easily) testable code:

```html
data:text/html,<form action="http:sprunge.us" method="POST"><textarea></textarea><button type="submit">
```

Comment: You ought to be able to replace `http:` with `//`.

Comment: @Jordan not for me? I think that looks for a file, not a http:// address.

Comment: `//sprunge.us` is a [protocol-relative URL](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), so if it appears on an HTTPS site it'll resolve to `https://sprunge.us` and if it appears on an HTTP site it'll resolve to `http://sprunge.us`, so it might not work if you're trying it on an HTTPS site and sprunge.us only works with HTTP. Barring that, I dunno, and I'm not at a computer so it's impractical for me to test. Sorry!

Comment: @Jordan it doesn't work, that's all I know.